# What is Matlab's colon operator called?

Tags: matlab

When teaching people about Matlab, it would be very nice if I could refer to Matlab's colon operator as something other than just "the colon operator".  As you can read on this [Mathworks blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/11/10/all-about-the-colon-operator/), the operator has a number of different contexts. I'm referring specifically to the first use on that list, creating a list of numbers.

Does anyone have a clever phrase they use to refer to this operation?

Comment: Going the other (non-programming) direction: Colon operator = colorectal surgeon :)

Comment: So you propose to teach your students to use the phrase 'the wygywg operator' and then to have to explain to them that the Mathworks call the 'the wygywg operator' 'the colon operator' ?  So what if it has a variety of applications or interpretations, I still think your proposal is wrong-headed.  Note, that 'wygywg' is a word I made up you probably won't find it in an English dictionary.

Comment: Note that I'm asking about a name for the particular operation, not the operator.  Also, see tmpearce's interpretation regarding that stick.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about a practical programming problem, as laid out in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: It is called the colon operator. It has no other name. Answers below are fun, but meaningless, because nobody will recognize those names.

Answer (score 4):

I would call it the "range operator".

Answer (score 0):

[Linear Space Vector Generator](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) would also do I think ...