# What is the colon operator doing here?

Tags: matlab, vector

What are these lines of code doing?

```
x0 = rand(n,2)
x0(:,1)=W*x0(:,1)
x0(:,2)=H*x0(:,2)
x0=x0(:)
```

Is this just one big column vector?

Comment: Here they're used for selecting columns of `x0`. You might want to consider checking out the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) for some more details.

Comment: @Julius I'd say the colon in this case is selecting the rows of `x0` (all in this case), and not the column. You indeed end up with a column vector.

Comment: @rinkert in the end, yes. Here `x0(:, 1)` selects a column, and `x0(:)` reshapes `x0` into a single column vector.

Answer (score 3):

I'd encourage you to take a [MATLAB Tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) as indexing arrays is a fundamental skill. Also see [Basic Concepts in MATLAB](http://www4.ncsu.edu/%7Ekay/Basic_Concepts_in_Matlab.pdf).  Line-by-line descriptions are below to get you started.

> What are these lines of code doing?

Let's take this line by line.
**1.** This line uses [`rand()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) to generate an **n x 2** matrix of [uniform random numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) (**~U(0,1)**).
`x0 = rand(n,2)    % Generate nx2 matrix of U(0,1) random numbers`

**2.** Multiply the first column by `W`
In this case, `x0(:,1)` means take **all rows** of `x0` (the colon in the first argument) and the **1st column** (the 1). Here, the `*` operator indicates `W` is a scalar or an appropriately sized array for feasible matrix multiplication (my guess is a scalar). The notation `.*` can be used for element-by-element multiplication; see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) for more details.
`x0(:,1)=W*x0(:,1)    % Multiply (all rows) 1st column by W`

**3.** Multiply the first column by `H`.
Using similar logic as #2.
`x0(:,2)=H*x0(:,2)    % Multiply (all rows) 2nd column by H`

**4.** Force column
The `x0(:)` takes the array `x0` and forces all elements into a single column.

From the documentation for [colon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html):

> A(:) reshapes all elements of A into a single column vector. This has
> no effect if A is already a column vector.

---

A related operation is **forcing a row vector** by combining this with the [transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) operator.
For example, try the following:  `x0(:).'`

```
x0 = x0(:)       % Force Column
x0 = x0(:).'     % Force Row
```

---

**Related Posts:**
[What is Matlab's colon operator called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12075057/8239061)
[How does MATLAB's colon operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49377234/8239061)
[Combination of colon-operations in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12105271/8239061)